# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn not recognize external screens attached via USB C Hub

Tags: 18.04, drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have an [MSI GF638RD](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GF63-8RD) laptop model. With which I wanted to attach two external screens. For that I have a USB-C hub from [Fitfort](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/UCN-3278/dp/B085ZNBSGN/ref=psdc_1626220031_t3_B07MKC5Z1D). When I plug in the hub, it turtns on and every usb attached to the hub is recognised and works very well, but none of screens through HDMI are recognised. As a workaoround from some other questions on the forum I did a few steps but they didn't helped like changing the display managers, powering up the hub from external sources. Also ethernet connected from hub is also working fine. The only thing not working from the hub is just the two monitors from HDMI ports. Can anyone help me around to get the things working up?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: did you solve your problem?
If so, consider adding your solution as answer and mark it as solved.